# welcome resource ID #5

Tags: php, command-line

I keep getting this error when i try to read the content of a `txt` file:

*index.php:*

```
<?php
            $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
            $line = fgets($handle);
            fwrite(STDOUT, "Welcome $handle"); 
            ?>
```

in the command line i do: `cat texte.txt | php index.php`

where `texte.txt` contains a name. the two files txt and php are in the same folder. I used to work fine, i don't know why this error comes in my case.

Comment: [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a resource identifier, not the file contents. Demo: http://codepad.org/EPsrIlSZ

Answer (score 5):

Because you used to output `$line`, not `$handle`.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanx, so, if the file contain 4 lines, $handle will contain all lines and i have to display it line by line?

Comment: @Malek `$handle` doesn't "contain" lines... it's just a handle to tell php where to find more lines when you ask for them (with `fgets`, for example).

Comment: `$handle` is a handle to the file, and you will have to pass it to `fgets()` 4 times.

Comment: @Malek - See the PHP manual for an example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php#example-2115

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing PHP's string representation of "resource" objects/vars.  `fwrite` the `$line` and you should get your desired result.

Example:

```
<?php
echo fopen('foo.txt', 'r');
```

Outputs:

```
Resource id #2
```